Algebra problems involving constant and coefficient of exponential equations
The function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=a(3.7^x+3.7^b),$ where $a$ and $b$ are integer constants and $0<a<b$.
The functions $g$ and $h$ are equivalent to function $f$ where $k$ and $m$ are constants.
Which of the following equations displays the $y$-coordinate of the $y$-intercept of the graph of $y=f(x)$ in the $xy$-plane as a constant or coefficient?
I. $g(x)=a(3.7^x+k)$
II. $h(x)=a\cdot 3.7^x+m$
A.I only
B.II only
C. I and II
D. Neither I nor II
I get that when x=0, the y-intercept of the origincal function $f(x$) is $a*(1+3.7^b)$. Also given that $g$ and $h$ are equal to $f$. It is clear that k=$3.7^b$, and m=$a*3.7^b$. But then i am pretty lost here. I dont see the original y-intercept as a form of constant or coefficient here. So my best guess would be D.
